# Pasting filename of max raster onto plot

Tags: r, plot, raster

Im plotting 30 years worth of data using R. Ive created a list identical to my directory files and I can find which rasters exist in my WD and can calculate rasters such as max and min as well as ave. I want to export all of these plots but want to name the plots the filename that corresponds with the max, min and ave rasters.

```
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("Grey", "Blue"))
breakpoints <- c(0,50,100,150,200,250)
plot(maxr,breaks=breakpoints,col=colfunc(5), main=paste(Filenames[i]))
```

I want the paste function to paste in the name of the file that is the max, but i cant get to work without pasting the whole list of files.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to hold onto the index of the file that is the max and use that when outputting the plot?  I assume you are doing something like this?

```
totalMax <- 0
totalMaxIndex <- 0
for (i in 1:length(Filenames)){
    currentMax <- YourFunctionToCalculateMax(Filenames[i])
    if(currentMax > max)
    {
        totalMax <- currentMax
        totalMaxIndex <- i
    }
}
```

Then later

```
plot(maxr,breaks=breakpoints,col=colfunc(5), main=paste(Filenames[totalMaxIndex]))
```

Comment: That seemed to work for showing the dates, however, im still having the issue where it lists the entire list of files, instead of the date for the max raster

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more clear.  You never mention the concept of a "date" in your original post so I'm not really sure where that is coming from